# Why does this http thread pool die (join), but keep functioning?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

The following code takes an initial string ('a', 'b', or 'c'), and the two thread types pass it back and forth, appending 'W' and 'H' to it repeatedly, marking that the Worker thread or the Http thread last handled the string.

The code is a simple test to try and eventually accomplish the following. The http thread pool will pull web pages, and the worker thread will add info to a db, and then give the http thread more urls to pull. They just go back and forth. I want both thread pools and queues to stay alive unless BOTH are empty simultaneously. (there are cases where one pool will temporarily run out of things to do, and I don't want it to join because it's companion thread pool will probably be adding more work to it's queue soon.)

In the following code, the http thread pool runs out of things to do almost immediately, and then joins. But you'll notice that the threads keep functioning.

- Why does it do this
- And how do I make it so neither queues can join until BOTH are simultaneously empty?

  ```
  from queue import Queue
  import threading
  import time

  class http(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
          self.queue = queue
          self.out_queue = out_queue

      def run(self):
          while True:
              row = self.queue.get()
              print(row)
              self.out_queue.put(row+'H')
              self.queue.task_done()

  class worker(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
          self.queue = queue
          self.out_queue = out_queue

      def run(self):
          while True:
              time.sleep(1)
              row = self.out_queue.get()
              self.queue.put(row+'W')
              self.out_queue.task_done()


  URL_THREAD_COUNT = 3
  rows = [chr(x) for x in range(97, 100)]

  def main():    
      queue = Queue()
      out_queue = Queue()


      #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance
      for i in range(URL_THREAD_COUNT):
          t = http(queue, out_queue)
          t.daemon = True
          t.start()

      #populate queue with data
      for row in rows:
          queue.put(row)

      #spawn worker thread
      dt = worker(queue, out_queue)
      dt.daemon = True
      dt.start()

      #time.sleep(5)

      # wait for queues
      queue.join()
      print('EXIT http')
      out_queue.join()
      print('EXIT worker')

  start = time.time()
  main()
  print("Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start))
  ```

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is literally no way to do what you want without a race, because what you want inherently makes no sense. If you want to know that all processing is done, you can't find that by checking that the queue is empty, you need something that actually means all processing is done—a semaphore, a sentinel job, etc.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you trying to build this yourself in the first place? Why not use the thread pool in `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` or the executor in `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or any of the many implementations on PyPI? It's not that it isn't worth knowing how to do this from scratch, but it's much easier to learn by building some code with a working thread pool and then looking at the source to that thread pool than by trying to re-invent the wheel from basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"joining" a queue waits until the queue is empty. If worker finishes processing some out_queue messages before the other threads can add more messages, the outer out_queue.join thinks you are done. You may want to add a control message that tells the threads when their work is done so that they can exit, and call thread.join() for them all instead. That will mean keeping a list of threads created in the for loop instead of just abandoning them.